# How can I use mutate() with a string column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble something like

`data <- tibble(string = c("A", "B", "C"), number = c(1,2,3))`

Then I defined a function

```
foo <- function(string, number){
  result <- paste(replicate(number, string), collapse = "")
  return(result)
}
```

so that `foo("A", 3) = "AAA"`. Now what I want to do is to add a new column `new` where the value for each row is `foo(s, n)`, given that `s` and `n` are the values of `string` and `number` for the same row. I tried to do this by doing something like

`mutate(data, new = foo(string, number))`

but I failed and don't know why.

Comment: There is a dedicated function to do this `strrep(string, number)`.

Comment: The function `foo()` was defined like above for explanatory purpose. The actual function I defined does NOT look like that. It is a function that takes string and double as arguments. And still, I don't get  the reason why `mutate()` works for `strrep()` and doesn't work for `foo()`.

Comment: I get ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new`.
x invalid 'length' argument
i Input `new` is `foo(string, number)`.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rowwise`, therefore `foo` is calculated for each row.

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = foo(string, number))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  string number new  
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 A           1 A    
2 B           2 BB   
3 C           3 CCC
```

The problem might be that `foo` cant handle vectors. Like in this examples.
So a rowwise apprach is needed.

```
foo(c("A", "B"), c(1,2))
# Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument 

foo(data$string, data$number)
# Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, there is no need to define a new function.  This will work-

```
data %>% mutate(new = strrep(string, number))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  string number new  
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 A           1 A    
2 B           2 BB   
3 C           3 CCC
```